# discretizing first order nonlinear equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to discretize below equations

$$ \partial_t f(t) = \cos(f(t)) g(x,y,t) $$
 $$ \partial_t x(t) = a \cos(f(t))$$

$x$ and $y$ are coordinate in 2D. $a$ is a constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one derivative, and so any ODE discretization works here.

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \approx \frac{f(t+\Delta t)-f(t)}{\Delta t}=\cos {f(t)} g(x,y,t) $$

Comment: If there is a noise term with gaussian distribution in right handsite of equation, Does the discretiation changes?

Comment: @OliverRange, is the distribution in $t$, or spatial?

Comment: no, it doesn't depend on t

Comment: But there is another equation which is coupled to this equation. I have just added it

Answer (score 0):

You have a first order ODE system which can be solved very accurately with a 4th order Runge-Kutta algorithm.

Comment: I need a complete soluton